# C Installed Library - What is this?

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to install a library in c (specifically libsndfile). It's telling me that I need to 'install' and library. I'm confused, what exactly am I doing by 'installing' the library?

Why is it that I'm not just including header and source code files?

I've tried googling this but have not gotten too much success. Does anyone care to explain or recommend an article that discusses this?

Thank you,

Comment: Installing a library is just putting the relevant files in the various locations whereby the compiler/linker can find them. This may also include any other files that the library requires - configuration files for example

Comment: @EdHeal, can you provide further information? I would like to understand it at a lower level.

Comment: What more information do you require? It possibility creates a few files specific to your set up. It then copies files to the relevant locations and sets the various file permissions. The installer can do other things but that is usually the sum total

Comment: If you were to write a program with an installed library, would it be possible to distribute it to other users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to include the header files your project needs to know where those header files are.  You *could* tell your pre-processor where they are, usually with `-I`, but for convenience your system has a set of directories it will search by default. This is called an "include path". Places like `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include` and the like are typical.

Installing a library usually means putting it in an include path.  sndfile.h will probably go into `/usr/local/include/sndfile.h`.

The code in the library is a little different. The install process will compile the code into a [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) that all processes can use. By using the shared library, rather than compiling it into every program, this reduces code size and memory usage system wide. Like the header file, shared libraries are found in a library path.  `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` are common examples.

Shared libraries also have the advantage that one it's upgraded, every program that's using it also gets upgraded.  This is very good for fixing bugs and plugging security holes.  The downside is if a shared library introduces a bug or security hole, or changes its interface, it effect every program using it.

---

The install process should be documented in the `README` or `INSTALL` file of the project source.  Typically it's...

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

But usually you can do this safer and easier with your package manager.  For example, [Debian has a libsndfile package](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/libsndfile) as does [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsndfile).  That way it will be kept up to date.

---

If you want to distribute a program which relies on another library, you have three choices.

First is to make the users manually install that library.  This is a pain for most users.

Next is to use a packaging system, [like that which comes with Ubuntu](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html), and turn your software into a package.  Then it can declare a dependency on the library's package.  This is good, but it requires making a package for every major distribution.

You can distribute the library along with your source code.  When your source code is built, build the library as well.  If you distribute your program as a binary, you can distribute the compiled library as well.  This is what a lot of applications are these days: directories full of compiled code and all their necessary support libraries and frameworks.  An example is [the OS X .app bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html).